# Double quotes in a specific column using awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk

I have this input:

```
##gff-version 3
chr1    TAIR10  mRNA    3631    5899    .   +   .   ID AT1G01010.1 ;geneID AT1G01010 ;gene_name AT1G01010
chr1    TAIR10  exon    3631    3913    .   +   .   Parent AT1G01010.1
chr1    TAIR10  exon    3996    4276    .   +   .   Parent AT1G01010.1
chr1    TAIR10  exon    4486    4605    .   +   .   Parent AT1G01010.1
chr1    TAIR10  exon    4706    5095    .   +   .   Parent AT1G01010.1
chr1    TAIR10  exon    5174    5326    .   +   .   Parent AT1G01010.1
chr1    TAIR10  exon    5439    5899    .   +   .   Parent AT1G01010.1
```

I want that the ID, geneID, and gene_name have double quotes like the next output:

```
  ##gff-version 3
    chr1    TAIR10  mRNA    3631    5899    .   +   .   ID "AT1G01010.1" ;geneID "AT1G01010" ;gene_name "AT1G01010"
    chr1    TAIR10  exon    3631    3913    .   +   .   Parent "AT1G01010.1"
    chr1    TAIR10  exon    3996    4276    .   +   .   Parent "AT1G01010.1"
    chr1    TAIR10  exon    4486    4605    .   +   .   Parent "AT1G01010.1"
    chr1    TAIR10  exon    4706    5095    .   +   .   Parent "AT1G01010.1"
    chr1    TAIR10  exon    5174    5326    .   +   .   Parent "AT1G01010.1"
    chr1    TAIR10  exon    5439    5899    .   +   .   Parent "AT1G01010.1"
```

I have been testing with

```
awk '{sub($10, "\"&\""); print}' file.gtf
```

Thanks for read my question

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty

`sed -E 's#(ID|Parent|gene_name) ([0-9A-Za-z.]+)#\1 \"\2\"#g'`